# How to translate "If the third element in data array is not blank, show table; if not, return blank" into Google Apps Script Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table that I only want to show if one element on my data array from Google Sheets is not blank. The data array is returned from a **search function** (I enter an ID, and the function searches my Google Sheet).

So I tried all the following but all of them did not show the table at all even if it should've (the code for my table and return blank is all good, just the "if" part is what I don't get):

```
function table(dataArray) {
if(dataArray[2] !== "")
```

.

```
function table(dataArray) {
if(dataArray[2] === "<I inserted here the actual value of a non-blank cell>")
```

.

```
function table(dataArray) {
if(dataArray[2] !== null)
```

.

```
function table(dataArray) {
if(dataArray[2] && dataArray[2] !== undefined && dataArray[2].length != 0)
```

.

```
function table(dataArray[2]) {
if(dataArray[2] && dataArray[2] !== undefined && dataArray[2].length != 0)
```

Comment: Are you checking the right array element? The second element in the array will be `dataArray[1]`...

Comment: @Daniel Beck Oh yeah! Sorry I put second in the title instead of third. I meant third haha, thanks for the correction! Idk why I couldn’t tag you properly on mobile

Comment: What is in your 'dataArray'.  Is it a flat array or a 2D array?

Comment: @Kris This helped me solve it, thank you! I thought it was 1D but it was 2D, so it should've been "!dataArray[0][2]" instead of just [2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple null check to see if the cell you are referring to is null using the code below:

```
if(!dataArray[2])
```

Comment: Thank you! My mind went completely blank last night that I didn't think to check using a logger too. And your answer did the job! Thanks again!